# Error in Arduino Si7021 temp and humidity sensor code

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm having an issue with this code

```
exit status 1
'httpResponseCode' was not declared in this scope
```

I'm trying to create a temp & humidity sensor with ESP32 and Si702, I want it to also show up on the LED screen.

Here is the full code

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>,

const char* ssid = "Test1";
const char* password = "Test2";

const char* serverName = "localhost/Temp/insert.php";

String apiKeyValue = "tPmAT5Ab3j7F9";

String sensorName = "S17021";
String sensorLocation = "Class";

float humidity = 0; 
float temp = 0;

Weather sensor;

void loop() {
  if(httpResponseCode>0) {
    Serial.println("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
}
http.end();
else {
  Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
}
```

Comment: Try to include a little more context for questions when using the site.

From the sidebar when submitting a question... 

"Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs."

Comment: your code in incomplete....

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear about what is wrong.

httpResponseCode was not declared in this scope.

```
 if(httpResponseCode>0) {
    Serial.println("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
```

You're using it without having declared it first. The compiler doesn't know that variable.

Also your code does not have a `setup` function which is mandatory for an Arduino sketch.

Comment: What is the setup function for? What do I need to put in there

Comment: @Bruh would you please do an Adruino tutorial and read the manual? the way you're approaching this is not good. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BareMinimum

Comment: I would but its a school assignment that I have to hand in soon and I don't have time to do that

Comment: they wont ask any questions, I don't have time to learn basics or anything else, I have to hand it in today